# Apache Drill: How to query all files in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-drill

I am using Apache Drill 1.10 on OSX. I have an S3 bucket with about 150 files in, and I have set up [a connection between the two as per the Drill documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/s3-storage-plugin/).

I can see all the files in the bucket, from Drill:

```
jdbc:drill:zk=local> USE `s3`.`root`;
+-------+--------------------------------------+
|  ok   |               summary                |
+-------+--------------------------------------+
| true  | Default schema changed to [s3.root]  |
+-------+--------------------------------------+
1 row selected (1.123 seconds)

jdbc:drill:zk=local> SHOW files; 
<shows table of 15 files>
```

And I can query individual files successfully:

```
jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from s3.`ocds-b5fd17-00ec7c92-54f3-4c50-8214-8b8c0cf9ff09-140281-qc54303.json`;
<returns results>
```

But how do I query across the whole directory? On the local filesystem I'd just supply a wildcard like `dfs`.`/path/*.json`, but that doesn't seem to work with S3:

```
jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from s3.`*.json`;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Can not create a Path from an empty string
SQL Query null
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured this out, recording it here for the benefit of anyone else with the same problem.

Create a directory in the root of the bucket, called e.g. `releases`, and put the files in there.

Then you can just query all files in the directory with:

```
select * from s3.`releases`;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query will run over the root directory:

```
select * from s3.`.`;
```

Comment: does not work for me.It throws "org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: UnresolvedAddressException"